# Block vs Context positioning facet block filter

Tags: blocks, 7, search

I have a Drupal Commerce site with faceted search ([Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) + db index + [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and facet blocks).
My setup is as follow :
- Catalogue view (based on my search index)
- Facet filters block placed with context when i'm on my catalogue View page

Everything worked fine since a few days when we realized the facet block wouldn't show up in our catalogue page anymore.

**BEFORE :**
I placed my blocks with context, everything would work fine. 
Block appeared with list of filters

**NOW :**
Nothing changed in my context setup, but my facet block appear with nothing (no filter).
We didn't commit (we use feature) anything related to the Search settings, facet or context.

**WORKAROUND (dirty?) :**
We managed to correctly display our facet blocks by doing the following :

- I set up the block visibility in the Block configuration page by placing them in the right region (the same as the one in my context), and no page / url filter
- My Context is activated when I go on my catalogue page, and it works fine.

**[edit]**
*Actually, I just need to make 1 facet block available to any region to have all my context blocks appear correctly. WEIRD !!!*

If reset the facet block configuration in the Block configuration page (display them in no region), my context would activate, but display facet with no filter ...

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Thanks